# which platform on facebook for developers to choose?

Tags: java, facebook, chatbot

I made a chat bot for facebook messenger and now to complete I need to send it for verification (pages_messaging permission). And when submitting, I am asked to select a platform (to enter?). I don’t understand which one to choose and why, if to contact the bot it’s enough to find a page on Facebook.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLgr6.png)
I've looked at a lot of documentation but still can't figure it out.

Comment: We can't possibly figure it out either, since we know nothing about your application. What operating system/plaftform does your application run on?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I created a page on facebook, to which the chat bot (for messenger) was connected. I created this bot with java and deployed it to heroku. Nothing more, I need people to be able to find this page on facebook and send a message, nothing more

Comment: Add the Website platform, and point it to something on your heroku webspace. You're going to need a valid privacy policy in any case, so you will have to place _some_ web content there anyway.

Comment: @CBroe this is my first application, can you advise whether it is better to place the policy on heroku or can I leave it on freeprivacypolicy.com ?

Comment: Should not matter too much, as long as the Facebook scraper can read the URL. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.